What is this "/|\" symbol on the enclosures of various appliances?
I keep seeing this symbol on old electronics appliances of varying types.

Two examples that I own...
Early 1960's portable "Megger" insulation tester

July 1969 Marconi attenuator

I have also seen this on other equipment manufactured as late as the 1980's, such as an HP 3314A signal generator.
So, it appears that this is a standard symbol, and not a proprietary one.
What does it mean?

Final edit to add another photo as supporting evidence for @Spehro Pefhany's answer


Tried a Google image search? You'd soon find the answer if you did.

UK MoD perchance?

@Finbarr, yes but the symbol is so primitive that I get a large number of unrelated hits.

Worth noting that it closely resembles the symbol used for an antenna in electrical diagrams (though inverted).  I imagine this could cause confusion on certain electronic devices.

@Finbarr what a classically helpful passive aggressive stack exchange answer. thanks for your contribution and assumption that OP is an idiot.

The Broad Arrow (aka 'pheon') indicates that the item in question was once (British) Government property - a Crown asset.


There's a nice picture of a voltmeter with such a symbol in the wikipedia article too.

Fascinating.  The "Megger" device I own bears the brand "A.M." and a crown logo literally burned into its leather carry case.  I didn't put these two clues together!  A.M. stood for Air Ministry which later became the Ministry of Defence in 1964.  I'll add a photo...

Obviously I need to find an early 14th century piece of test and measurement gear to complete my historic collection! :)  I find this amazing - that a symbol was used many hundreds of years and is still visible today on equipment that still works!  History is truly amazing.

This is getting spooky now.  An old sandstone bridge that I walk over every day on my way to work has this symbol carved into it.

@Wossname The human brain filters a lot of stuff out. Once you've gone on a type of long walk, for example, you start noticing these symbols all over the place.

@Wossname That is probably an Ordnance Survey benchmark.

The use of this arrow by the UK government/military often gets mentioned on (UK) antiques programs like Antiques Roadtrip or Flog It! (including one I saw earlier today!)

They put the arrows on prisoners (prison uniforms) as well. https://web.archive.org/web/20240519210150/https://www.dartmoor-prison.co.uk/

@TripeHound Also Kipling mentions a "government broad-arrow" formation in a polo game.
